# Defining functions of varying, iterative numbers of arguments

Tags: function-construction

The following is an edit of this post, for which a working solution was provided by John McGee. I have a different function and am not sure how to adapt the solution for it:

I want to construct a function that accepts multiple arguments, but where the number of arguments can change according to the length of a list that I insert as the set of arguments. For example, I have a table which has as elements the following lists:

> {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,5,6},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, ...}

Note that the first list within the table has a length of 4, with progressive lists having an extra length of 2 compared to its previous. I have created the following function which works for the first list in the table:

```
f[{a,b,c,d}]:= (y[2] - c)*(y[2] - d)*Exp[2y[1](a - b) + (a^2 - b^2)+ 2y[2](c - d) + (c^2 - d^2)]
```

Similarly the function for the second list in the table should be:

```
f[{a,b,c,d,e,f}]:= (y[3] - e)*(y[3] - f)*Exp[2y[1](a - b) + (a^2 - b^2)+ 2y[2](c - d) + (c^2 - d^2) + 2y[3](e - f) + (e^2 - f^2)]
```

There is a pattern which obeys the following:

1. The coefficient in front of the exponential is always (y[n]- (element 1 of nth pair))*(y[n]- (element 2 of nth pair)) - where n is the number of the nth pair of elements in the list - i.e. for 3 pairs n would be 3 etc.
2. In the exponent, the argument of y is the number of the pair being considered and the terms within the parenthesis is similarly the first element of each pair minus the second element of each pair.

I want to create a table that has as elements the result of the function. So the first element of such a table will be the evaluation to the above. The second element of the table should be the evaluation of the function also written explicitly above and so on.

How can I create the general function that accepts a varying number of arguments? I will need to loop over this function to assess it for the different lists in the table above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that if you want to form an *arbitrary* function of different variables, you'll have to write each explicitly.  If however you have sum general form (such as `Total`, then you can use functions that apply to arbitrary lists.

Comment: This has been answered in the following [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75726/general-function-taking-general-number-of-arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
efunc[t_] := Exp@Total@((#[[2]]^2 - #1[[1]]^2) & /@ Partition[t, 2]);
```

Where t is a list with an even number of elements.

Comment: Thanks John, this works for my case of even number of elements. What would I have to do if there were odd number of elements?