# Function taking arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: function-construction

I have a very similar function to that which a solution was provided by kguler, but am unsure as to how to adapt the solution that was given there. That post can be seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75726/general-function-taking-general-number-of-arguments). The adaptation is only slight but I will explain it fully below.

I want to construct a function that accepts multiple arguments, but where the number of arguments can change according to the length of a list that I insert as the set of arguments. For example, I have a table which has as elements the following lists:

```
{{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,5,6},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, ...}
```

Note that the first list within the table has a length of 4, with progressive lists having an extra length of 2 compared to its previous. I have created the following function which works for the first list in the table:

```
f[{a,b,c,d}]:= (y[2] - c)*Exp[2y[1](a - b) + (a^2 - b^2)+ 2y[2](c - d) + (c^2 - d^2)]
```

Similarly the function for the second list in the table should be:

```
f[{a,b,c,d,e,f}]:= (y[3] - e)*Exp[2y[1](a - b) + (a^2 - b^2)+ 2y[2](c - d) +
                  (c^2 - d^2) + 2y[3](e - f) + (e^2 - f^2)]
```

The main difference to the similar previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75726/general-function-taking-general-number-of-arguments) is the factor in front of the exponential. There is a pattern which obeys the following:

1. The coefficient in front of the exponential is always (y[n]- (element 1 of nth pair)) - where n is the number of the nth pair of elements in the list - i.e. for 3 pairs n would be 3 etc.
2. In the exponent, the argument of y is the number of the pair being considered and the terms within the parenthesis is similarly the first element of each pair minus the second element of each pair.

I want to create a table that has as elements the result of the function. So the first element of such a table will be the evaluation to the above. The second element of the table should be the evaluation of the function also written explicitly above and so on.

How can I create the general function that accepts a varying number of arguments? I will need to loop over this function to assess it for the different lists in the table above.

The solution of this should only be a variation of the solution that was provided by kguler [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75726/general-function-taking-general-number-of-arguments), but I can't get it to work at the moment. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a minor modification of the answer in the linked Q/A:

```
ClearAll[eF2]
eF2[z_: y] := Module[{j = 1, p = Partition[#, 2]}, 
   First[(z[Length@p] - p[[-1, 1]]) Exp[Total[(Subtract[##] 2 z[j++] + {# - #2}^2) & @@@ p]]]] &
```

Examples:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f]
eF2[][{a, b, c, d}]
(* E^((a-b)^2+(c-d)^2+2 (a-b) y[1]+2 (c-d) y[2]) (-c+y[2]) *)
eF2[][{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
(* E^((a-b)^2+(c-d)^2+(e-f)^2+2 (a-b) y[1]+2 (c-d) y[2]+2 (e-f) y[3]) (-e+y[3]) *)
```

Comment: Thanks kguler, this works just fine - I also understand how the functions works now! For future reference, if I have a similar but slightly different question, is there any way I can ask it other than to start a new post? Namely, could I have asked this question on the linked Q/A and brought it to your attention?

Comment: @Jas, you can use comments to an answer to ask closely related questions. The answerer is notified about comments on his/her post.