# Manipulating a general length function

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching

As a minimal example, define a function like `s[1,2,3]`; this is a function of three arguments in this case, but I'd like to apply this general idea to functions like `s[3,4,5,6,7]` which don't necessarily start at 1.

From an identity from theory, I need to re-express this as as sum of 2-argument functions that cycle over all of the possible combinations of the original function, but don't duplicate. Explicitly, this would be the same as writing

`s[1,2,3]=f[1,2]+f[1,3]+f[2,3`],

or in the longer more general case (and to illustrate my point)

```
s[3,4,5,6,7] = f[3,4]+f[3,5]+f[3,6]+f[3,7]+f[4,5]+f[4,6]+f[4,7]+f[5,6]+f[5,7]+f[6,7]
```

I was previously using the definition with simple replacement rules for each of the these chains, with general cases of `s[i_,j_,k_]` and such similar rules. However, this isn't optimal in larger problems, where I have many thousands of these results, and leads to remarkably long evaluation times.

To see my functional but slow solution, I have attached a partial screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFhEU.png), but naturally, I think there must be a better method. I was considering using `Partitions`, as in [this SE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75726/general-function-taking-general-number-of-arguments) or BlankSpaces, but I struggle to implement more complex uses of these. Any guidance or other ideas would be gratefully appreciated. Also, a title suggestion would be great as well!

Comment: Look into `Subsets[listOfArguments, {2}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
ClearAll[s]
s[seq__] := Total[f@@@Subsets[List[seq], {2}]]
```

Comment: Hi @MarcoB - Subsets was indeed the function I was looking for. I was thinking perhaps of more of a general replacement rule at the end, where in my final stage I remove all of the (previously defined) functions s, in exchange for these functions p. I will try and play around and see if I can figure out how to create a replacement rule based on this method. Thank you for your help:

Comment: After changing my definition of recursion to work with a symbolic `sX`, which actually makes evaluations much much faster overall, I can utilise this to get exactly what I need. Thank you all for your help, this is the fastest solution I found.

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[s]
s[f_] := Total @ Subsets[f @ ##, {2}] &;

s[f][a, b, c]
```

> f[a, b] + f[a, c] + f[b, c]

```
s[f][3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

> f[3, 4] + f[3, 5] + f[3, 6] + f[3, 7] + f[4, 5] + f[4, 6] + f[4, 7] + 
>    f[5, 6] + f[5, 7] + f[6, 7]